# Calculate 2nd and 3rd coordinate of a triangle

Tags: circles, triangles, polar-coordinates

I'm working on a project to place a piece of text, programatically, in the center of each segment of a doughnut chart. To make things easier, I'm ignoring the arc of the segment and instead treating it as a triangle.

I understand that if I know the coordinates of the three triangle vertices, I can use a formula to calculate the center point.

At the moment, I know the following information about each possible triangle:

- The size of each inside angle
- Each triangle will be isosceles
- The length of the equal sides will be equal to the radius of the doughnut chart
- The x and y coordinate of one vertex will always be the midpoint of the doughnut chart, which will be equal to the radius of the doughnut chart. (Eg, given a chart with a radius of 300, the coordinate of the midpoint of the chart will be (300,300)

I have included an illustration of the above below:

[image: Diagram image, please view]

On the diagram, the two coordinates I am trying to find are A and B. (A second triangle has been included to illustrate how each segment will be identical, bar the coordinates that touch the outer rim of the circle.)

Unfortunately, due to the nature of the program that I am trying to write, there are some restrictions:

- Triangles are drawn one at a time. This means that after one triangle is drawn, the values for the other are lost. It is possible for me to save these if needed, however.
- The program is designed to dynamically create a doughnut charts. This means that it may create a doughnut chart of eight segments, six, five, nine, or less or more. Therefore, if possible, the solution to this problem should also be able to work on a triangle with different values.

In advance, thank you for your help on this. I've tried to explain my problem as clearly as I can. If I haven't, please ask as many questions as you need.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Two answers exist:

1. For one that works out the missing two vertices of the triangle, see Henry's answer below that I have marked as correct.
2. For one that solves my problem without calculating the missing vertices, see PM2Ring's answer in the comments to this question.

Comment: @Henry "each segment will be identical", so the centre angles are all the same.

Comment: Let's call the centre of the circle $O$ (for origin). Do you really need the coordinates of $A$, $B$, $C$ etc? Why not just calculate the coordinates of the midpoints of the triangles directly? If $A$ is at the top of the circle we can easily calculate those midpoints using $r\cos\theta$ and $r\sin\theta$ with $r$ = 2/3 the radius of the chart, so 200 in this case.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thank you! I'll try that now. Before I do, could you explain how to calculate the r cos 0 and r sin 0? As in, which equation should the x and y values go into?

Comment: In this problem, it makes sense to measure our angles from the vertical line $OA$, going anticlockwise, so we use $x=r\sin\theta, y=r\cos\theta$. Eg if there are 12 sectors, each sector occupies 30°, so for the 1st sector $\theta$=15°, for the second, $\theta$=45°, etc. Of course, in a program, you'll (probably) need to work in radians. And those coordinates are using $O$ as $(0, 0) $, so you'll need to shift them, eg `ox=oy=300; x=ox+r*sin(th); y=oy+r*cos(th)`

Comment: @PM2Ring Cheers. So I understand, "Eg if there are 12 sectors, each sector occupies 30°, so for the 1st sector θ=15°, for the second, θ=45°" Is this the angle of the midpoint for each segment? Yes, I'm working in radians in my program. However, I have a piece of code that converts from degrees to radians.

Comment: Yes, $\theta=15°, \theta=45°$ etc, are the angles of the midpoints.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks. On the third iteration of your formula, when θ=112.5 (where θ started at 22.5, for a graph of 8 segments) I receive the following:

x = r sin θ = 200*(sin(112.5)) = 196.1570561; y = r cos θ = 200*(cos(112.5)) = -39.0180644.

The x coordinate is, as far as implementing these numbers has shown, is correct. However, the y coordinate is not as it is off the grid. Have I done something wrong, or is there an error with the solution?

Comment: As I said earlier, if your coordinate system doesn't put the centre of the circle at (0, 0) then you need to shift the numbers. And if your $y$ coordinates get bigger as you go down the screen then you'll need to deal with that too. So if the centre of the circle is at $(300, 300)$, you'd do `ox=oy=300; x=ox+r*sin(th); y=oy-r*cos(th)` Note the negative sign in the formula for $y$. And make sure you give those trig functions radians!

Comment: So with $ox=oy=300, r=200, th=112.5°$ you should get $x=484.7759065, y=376.5366865$

Comment: Thank you so much, that works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have $n$ segments, are all the centre angles the same? E.g. with $n=8$ the centre angles are all $\dfrac{360^\circ}{8}=45^\circ$?

Are your co-ordinates measured from the top left corner?  So for example does Point A have co-ordinates $(300,0)$?

You might try making the $k^{\text{th}}$ triangle of $n$ have the co-ordinates $(300, 300)$ as the centre of the circle and $\left(300+300\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi (k-1)}{ n}\right), 300-300\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi (k-1)}{ n}\right)\right)$ and $\left(300+300\sin\left(\dfrac{2\pi k}{ n}\right), 300-300\cos\left(\dfrac{2\pi k)}{ n}\right)\right)$ on the assumption your computer applies trigonometric functions to radians

So in your illustration with $n=8$ and $k=1$ you would get Point A as $(300,0)$ and point B as about $(512, 88)$

Comment: Yes, all center angles will be the same and the coordinates are measured from the top left hand corner. I'm sorry, I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to trigonometry. I haven't done it for years. Could you explain your formula a little more?

Comment: If the centre of a circle is at coordinates $(0,0)$, then points on its circumference can have co-ordinates like $(r\cos (\theta), r \sin (\theta))$ where $r$ is the radius and $\theta$ is the angle round the circle.  In your case: $r=300$, the centre is at $(300,300)$ so this needs to be added, the angles are fractions of a full circle with $2\pi$ radians leading to things like $\frac{2 \pi k}{n}$, and your angles seem to start from the vertical going clockwise rather than the conventional horizontal going anticlockwise leading to other slight changes